# lua string get Nth number

Tags: string, lua

I am trying to find the Nth number in a string. Should i use string.find? If so, how? I know the arguments are the string to search and the pattern to find, but the 3rd argument (where to start) seems like it might just work.
[the lua string tutorial i am looking at](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial)

thanks!

Comment: `string.find` is not what you want to use. It simply finds a matching pattern, and while it can search by positions, it won't return what you're looking for.

Comment: Add an example to illustrate what the input is and what expect to get. For example, does the string contain non-number characters? What's between each numbers? It's not clear now.

Comment: `tonumber(str:gsub('%S*%d%S*','',n-1):match'%S*%d%S*')`

Comment: Yo Hao, it will contain numbers,letters,and symbols. So pretty much everything. No spaces. All of the letters will be lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a function that splits your string into an array. Once you've done this, you'll be able to return whatever number position you're looking for.

```
function findnth(str, nth)
  local array = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(str, "%d+") do
    table.insert(array, i)
  end
  return array[nth]
end
```

The function above works like so:

```
print(findnth("1 3 7 2 15 2", 4))
```

Returns:

```
2
```

**Edit**: Changed function to suit OP's specific needs.

Comment: Thank you, Josh. What is the del variable for?

Comment: You know, it was there to act as a delimiter, but it's not necessary. Revising the function to fit your need specifically.

Comment: There's no need to add them to the array; just return the 4th time through the loop.

Comment: If you're going to downvote and state "just return the 4th time through the loop", you could at least show how it's done, because as far as I can tell, this is the easiest way. Just a thought.